# Barebone ATSAMD11D14 not responding

Tags: atmel, debugging, atmel-studio, debugwire

[image]

I wire up this schematic on my breadboard. I've verified that the 3V3 LDO is working.  Atmel Studio on my Windows machine can see the Atmel ICE.  The simple blink compiles fine too. However, I cannot upload / debug code.  Either the Atmel ICE or the ATSAMD11D14 is not responding.  Hints for a n00b? Thanks!

Comment: Bypass capacitors, double check the wiring.  Take note of the fact that the pinout of the Atmel ICE is backwards from the standard so it is usually used with a flipped cable.  Should your MCU have a clock circuit?   Do you need to connect the reset to the ICE?   Can you try the ICE with another target?  What is the power consumption of your board with and without the reset asserted?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thank you for the suggestions.
I DID make two wiring mistakes:
1. I did not have reset connected.
2. I did not have VCC connected to the ICE. I thought ICE is powered by USB, but I saw it referred to as VTREF.
Once, I did that, I was able to get further. A few more configuration corrections in Atmel Studio later, I was able to blink the LED!  Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a forum where you mark threads as closed by editing the title.  Since you found the problem, you can post an answer, then accept that answer.  That will properly close things off.  If you don't do that, it will keep popping up on the front page until somebody gets fed up and has it closed.  Don't be the guy who leaves a mess behind him.

Comment: @JRE, I apologize for editing the title. I've added an answer as you suggested.  Let me know there is more I need to correct.

Comment: You should be able to accept your answer in a day or two.  If you do that, all will be well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I did not have reset and vcc (as a target voltage reference) of the ATSAMD11D14 connected to the Atmel ICE. Once I've done that, Atmel Studio was able to talk to the microcontroller.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ATSAMD11 documentation says it is also a good idea to have pull-up resisters on the ¬RST and SWCLK lines, a decoupling 100nF capacitor across VDD and GND pins, and if you want accurate timing (you might not) then a 32.768kHz crystal and caps on PA08/PA09 (XIN/XOUT).